How do I convert this Bedrock command to a Java Edition command?
Bedrock command:
execute @a[tag=T] ~~~ titleraw @s actionbar {"rawtext":[{"text":"§lNICKNAME:"},{"selector":"@s"},{"text":"\n§ePLAYTIME§f:"},{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"h"}},{"text":"HOUR "},{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"m"}},{"text":"MIN "},{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"s"}},{"text":"SEC "}]}

How do I convert this Bedrock command to a Java Edition command?

Would you have a screenshot of the intended output, so I could look at the expected result?

Here is the command I was able to create from what I could understand:
execute as @a[tag=T] run title @s actionbar [{"text":"NICKNAME: ","bold":"true"},{"selector":"@s"},{"text":" PLAYTIME","color":"yellow","reset":"true"},{"text":": ","color":"white"},{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"h"}},{"text":" HOUR "},{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"m"}},{"text":" MIN "},{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"s"}},{"text":" SEC"}]


To my knowledge you can't show a title on multiple lines in Java, thus I have just removed it. Otherwise, it would show this symbol:

